# Error en Java al pasar un tipo enumerado por parámetro de un método instancia

Tags: java, poo, enum, tipos

/*quiero crear un objeto fecha, donde el dia y el año son de tipo int, y el mes pretendo que sea un tipo enumerado, pero en la instanciación al pasar el argumento del mes me da error, que estoy haciendo mal?*/

```
public class PROG03_Ejerc1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         Fecha objFecha = new Fecha(4,Abr,1976);    // Abr cannot be resolved to a variable            
    }
}

class Fecha {

    private enum enumMes  {Ene,Feb,Mar,Abr,May,Jun,Jul,Ago,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dic};
    
    private int diaDelMes;    
    enumMes mes;
    private int año; 

    public Fecha(int diaDelMes, enumMes mes, int año) {
        this.diaDelMes = diaDelMes;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.año = año;
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías poner el error exacto que te da, no crees? "me da error" no nos ayuda mucho a saber qué está pasando. Aunque viendo la declaración de ese enumerado... si es un campo ***PRIVADO*** cómo quieres poder usarlo fuera de esa clase??? Para eso lo hiciste privado, para que no sea accesible desde fuera, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo recomendamble es declarar el enum como una variable en la misma clase y de ahí tomar su valor:

```
public class PROG03_Ejerc1 {
   
    private enum enumMes  {Ene,Feb,Mar,Abr,May,Jun,Jul,Ago,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dic};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fecha objFecha = new Fecha(4, enumMes.Abr, 1976);    // Abr cannot be resolved to a variable               
        System.out.println(objFecha);
        
    }

    static class Fecha {

        //private enum enumMes  {Ene,Feb,Mar,Abr,May,Jun,Jul,Ago,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dic};
        private int diaDelMes;
        enumMes mes;
        private int año;

        public Fecha(int diaDelMes, enumMes mes, int año) {
            this.diaDelMes = diaDelMes;
            this.mes = mes;
            this.año = año;
        }

        
    }

}
```

Pero esta es una forma de realizarlo tomando los valores del `enum` desde la clase `Fecha`, declarando tu `enum` de la siguiente forma:

```
public class PROG03_Ejerc1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fecha objFecha = new Fecha(4, Fecha.enumMes.Abr, 1976);    // Abr cannot be resolved to a variable               
        System.out.println(objFecha);
        
    }

    static class Fecha {

        //private enum enumMes  {Ene,Feb,Mar,Abr,May,Jun,Jul,Ago,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dic};
        private int diaDelMes;
        enumMes mes;
        private int año;

        public Fecha(int diaDelMes, enumMes mes, int año) {
            this.diaDelMes = diaDelMes;
            this.mes = mes;
            this.año = año;
        }

        public enum enumMes {
            Ene("Ene"), Feb("Feb"), Mar("Mar"), Abr("Abr"), May("May"), Jun("Jun"), Jul("Jul"), Ago("Ago"), Sep("Sep"), Oct("Oct"), Nov("Nov"), Dic("Dic");
            private String value;

            enumMes(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

así no tendrás problema para declarar el mes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

La declaración de tu enumeración es privada para  la clase Fecha, por lo tanto, en main no puedes utilizar "Abr" porque supongo que debe darte variable no definida. Saca el enum hacia afuera o declarada como  public static en Fecha y utilizas  Fecha.Abr.